# My vertices disconnect

Tags: mesh, vertices

I posted this a while back but no one has replied in months so I am reposting. 
When I click on a vertex it moves one "triangle" (I'm new ok idk what the proper word is) and the rest stay in the same place. I'm trying to lips sync and it's proving to be impossible at the moment, due to the vertices being unconnected. 
Here is my blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/8nt27wz1lc414g0/newtester.blend 
Any help would be largely appreciated ^^
I have tried: 
right clicking and then pressing G
Pressing H
Pressing C

Comment: Try going to edit mode, selecting all vertices with A, then click W and select remove doubles.

Comment: your original post is here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34472/i-cant-select-multiple-vertices-and-move-them-blender-2-75

Answer (score 3):

That's because each triangle in that model is 'disjointed' , it is not joined to any other triangle. You can join them using **Remove Doubles**.

In Edit mode, hit <kbd>A</kbd> until Blender selects every polygon (Triangle). Then look for the tools menu, and press Remove Doubles.

[image]